# Create a list of elements and get matching element on a different key of the dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, indexing

In a dictionary, I want to give a element in a key and get the correspond element on a different key of the dictionary.

Example: if I give **letter b** i want to get **2**. if i give **letter f**, I want to get **1**

```
d = {'letter': {'a','b','c','d','e','f'}, 'number': {5,2,4,9,3,1}}
```

Imagine I want to have letter b and f

```
listing = ['b','f']
```

```
position= d['letter'].index(listing)

goal = d['number'][position]

print(goal)
```

it shows error 'set' object has no attribute 'index' or when i try different stuff 'set' object is not subscriptable

Comment: So you want to get the corresponding element at a particular index? This won't work because in `d` you use `set`s which do not have order.

Comment: ok.. and is there any way of solving it ?

Comment: If instead, you used `list`s, then `d = dict(zip(d["letter"], d["number"]))` would create a new dictionary where you could simply call `d["f"]` to get your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comments, you can do the following.

```
d = {'letter': ['a','b','c','d','e','f'], 'number': [5,2,4,9,3,1]}
d = dict(zip(d["letter"], d["number"]))
# {'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'd': 9, 'e': 3, 'f': 1}
```

Notice the square `[` `]` brackets around the lists, as these are lists (which have order) not sets (which do not have order). You could do all of this in one line by just declaring `d` as:

```
d = {'a': 5, 'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'd': 9, 'e': 3, 'f': 1}
```

The behaviour you request of looking up an item with a key is the behaviour provided by the dictionary. If you still need access to the letters alone, use `d.keys()` and the numbers alone can be accessed with `d.values()`.